# Postgres database backup error - special character in password

Tags: database, postgresql, backup, postgresql-9.3

I'm trying to take a PostgreSQL backup with `pg_dump`. But I'm not able to take it due to the following error.

I have successfully taken backups for different IP addresses **without** the special character `@` in it.

**command used and working**

```bash
sudo /usr/bin/pg_dump --file "/home/myusername/my_first_db.backup" \
  --verbose --format=t --blobs -v \
  --dbname postgresql://postgres:myfirstpassowrd@112.112.113.114:5432/my_first_db
```

**command used and not working**

```bash
sudo /usr/bin/pg_dump --file "/home/myuser/xyz_db/DB_BACKUP/db_file.backup" \
  --verbose --format=t --blobs -v  \
  --dbname postgresql://111.222.333.444:5432/prod_live?password=123th@123th4&user=postgres

sudo /usr/bin/pg_dump --file "/home/myuser/xyz_db/DB_BACKUP/db_file.backup" \
  --verbose --format=t --blobs -v  \
  --dbname postgresql://111.222.333.444:5432/prod_live?password=123th%40123th4&user=postgres
```

**Error I'm getting:**

```text
[4] 8555
myuser@myuser:~$ pg_dump: [archiver (db)] connection to database "prod_live" failed: FATAL:  password authentication failed for user "root"
FATAL:  password authentication failed for user "root"
```

I cannot change the password, because it is production.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I can see...
Unquoted character `&` in your command line sends the task to background as described, for example, here: [Linux: Start Command In Background](https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/linux-command-line-run-in-background/). So anything after `&` character ignored (or interpreted as separate command) by *nix shell.
**Solution**
Just try to quote the whole string like this:

```bash
sudo /usr/bin/pg_dump --file "/home/myuser/xyz_db/DB_BACKUP/db_file.backup" \
  --verbose --format=t --blobs -v  \
  --dbname 'postgresql://111.222.333.444:5432/prod_live?password=123th@123th4&user=postgres'
```

**Explanation**
In the output provided by you the line `[4] 8555` means `Background job #4 with process ID 8555 was started`
And single quotes around the string allows to interpret it "as-is", without parameters substitution and other special characters interpreting.

PS: Use `$'...'` syntax to translate special escaped characters like `\n` `\t` `\uxxxx` and others.

There is several examples:

```
$ echo abc&defgh
[1] 3426
abc
defgh: command not found
[1]+  Done                    echo abc
```

As you can see the output is like to provided by you in the part `[x] xxxx`

```
$ echo 'abc&defgh'
abc&defgh
```

In this case command `echo` prints exactly what you want
And last but not least:

```
$ echo '1: abc&\ndefgh'; echo $'2: abc&\ndefgh'
1: abc&\ndefgh
2: abc&
defgh
```

Comment: thank you.. this is working.. I have added "" to every other parameter out there. But i forgot to add to the dbname param..

Comment: @curious_one Actually single quotes is just one of several solutions. Look at this: `echo "abc&123"; echo abc'&'123; echo abc\&123` - all provides same output. Good luck.